# The usage of index on nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling, graph-databases

According to this part of this Neo4j book, Graph database engine find the location of a given node by multiplying it's ID and the size of the record which is 9 bytes. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK43d.png)

But I have read that If there is an index on the node, the db engine uses that index to find the location of the node very fast. If the engine can compute the location of the node very easily without the need of the index why do we need to put an index on the node?

Comment: In short, if you do happen to have the graph id of the node you want to look up, that will be fastest. But in most real queries, you never start with that, you instead want to look up nodes by property values, either direct, partial, or from some range or similar. That's why you create indexes on label/property combinations, so you can lookup this way.

Answer (score 0):

The passage you are looking at is talking about a node index. Meaning that the record of the nodes are stored as an index. This record does not contain the actual properties of the node though, just references to find that information. Since this is a node internal-id index, it only works for looking up nodes by internal id.

You need to create separate indexes on the properties of the nodes to find them without their id. Otherwise, the DB has to scan all nodes to find which ones have a property of a certain value.

TL:DR;
Don't worry how the database works. Leave that to a DB administrator because DBs are made of raw arcane black magic!